# Python cv2 throws strange symbol error when importing

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ubuntu

typically I can find the solution to any errors I have online, but I just cannot find the solution to this particular problem anywhere.

So I've installed OpenCV4 on my ubuntu 20.04 using pip3, but upon typing the following commands:

```
$ python3
import cv2
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jordan/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librsvg-2.so.2: undefined symbol: cairo_tag_end
```

I am not entirely sure what the error means. My guess is that it's something to do with the environment variables, but I don't know how to fix that anyways. I really hope someone can help me fix this.